# Best practice for application bootstrap in tests

Tags: micronaut

We were looking at how the application bootstrap relates to `EmbeddedServer` when running tests.
Our understanding so far, is that bootstrapping a Micronaut application could be something like this:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.build(args)
            .eagerInitSingletons(true) 
            .mainClass(Application.class)

            // plus some other stuff you might want to configure here

            .start();
    }
}
```

However, running an embedded server in a test, will do a lot of this stuff implicitly as far as we can tell, when doing:

```
EmbeddedServer server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
```

The code in the `main` method of `Application` is not relevant anymore, and a test might run with a slightly different app context configuration (and with out-of-the-box settings).

We can probably figure out a few solutions to make sure that the app context is loaded in the exact same way in both cases. But I first wanted to check that we're not missing a trick, and to see if Micronaut has any recommended practices for this scenario.

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/277

Comment: Thanks Jeff, and thank you for your prompt response! I think another, broader point here is: in order to have confidence of behaviour parity, we'd need in `@MicronautTest` an equivalent of every setting in `Micronaut` class. This will become impractical eventually. At the same time, most defaults are sensible enough (as they generally are in Micronaut!), so it's unlikely we'd need *all* of these settings to be manipulated via `@MicronautTest`. I just wanted to make sure we keep in mind that the broader point and design issue goes beyond eagerInitSingletons.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback